# Recover contacts from a deleted profile from Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-outlook, data-recovery

I deleted a profile in Outlook for Mac 2011.  My contacts were on this profile.  Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: Do you have a folder named **Microsoft User Data\Outlook 2011 Identities\[list of available identities]** in your Documents folder ? or in trash ?

Answer (score 0):

first, if you've just deleted it, chances are the file is still on your hard drive.

you need to IMMEDIATELY do a check for Unerase of recently deleted files.  And DO NOT SAVE ANYTHING NEW TO THIS DRIVE!!!

"Deleted" files aren't actually deleted.. The drive directory has simply been modified to remove their 'location' tabs, and the associated space is now free for use again.. So as soon as you save another file, it may overwrite that area, at which point your chances of getting those files back decrease exponentially.

Using a high quality app like FileSalvage or DiskDrill, you can unerase those drives.. howevr, you can't install it on that drive (due to the fact that installation or running that drive may well overwrite the files)...

SO.  you need to NOT run that machine; shut it down and boot it only in Target Disk mode, then do a recovery from another machine..

This takes time, but it's one of the consequences of deleting something that you needed.

If you have a TimeMachine drive, you can probably go to that drive and recover it via Time Machine.